# How to select unrelated entities with a single query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Let's imagine we have 5 tables that have no relationship between each other but all of them share the same column. Let's name the tables `ClojureConf`, `KotlinConf`, `ScalaConf`, `GroovyConf`, `JavaConf`. They all have a column `UserId`. The number and data types of other columns are different in each of them. A given User may have attended zero or more conferences.

The task is to just select all the records from each of the 5 tables for a given `UserId`, convert them to DTOs and return as json.

Currently the code does 5 trips to the database to get a list of results from each table.

Is there a library support in hibernate/jpa what would make a single trip to a database? The goal is to improve performance.

Is it possible to define a projection for entities that would look similar to this:

```
interface ConfAttended {

    List<ClojureConf> getClojureConfs();
    List<KotlinConf> getKotlinConfs();
    List<ScalaConf> getScalaConfs();
    List<GroovyConf> getGroovyConfs();
    List<JavaConf> getJavaConfs();

}
```

and a repository that would select and map the results in one go

```
interface ConfAttendedDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c, k, s, g, j FROM ClojureConf c " +
            "JOIN KotlinConf k ON c.UserId = k.UserId " +
            "JOIN ScalaConf s ON c.UserId = s.UserId " +
            "JOIN GroovyConf g ON c.UserId = g.UserId " +
            "JOIN JavaConf j ON c.UserId = j.UserId " +
            "WHERE c.UserId = :userId")
    ConfAttended findByUserIdForProjection(@Param("userId") long userId);

}
```

?

Comment: if you want to get 5 single records from 5 tables, and retrieve them all as a single row - all you need to do is use JOIN or CROSS APPLY , or LEFT join or OUTER APPLY.  you can join on the condition of selection - you seem to have that in your question

Comment: I want to investigate possible options. For a given `UserId` there may be 0 records in one table and 10 records in another. Is it possible to write a SELECT that would join all the columns from all the tables and populate missing with nulls or duplicated values?

Comment: JPQL does not allow use of "JOIN" syntax to unrelated entities.

Comment: Is there a way to issue a batch SELECT for unrelated entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having a query like this:

```
interface ConfAttendedDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c, k, s, g, j FROM User u " +
            "LEFT JOIN ClojureConf c ON c.UserId = :userId " +
            "LEFT JOIN KotlinConf k ON k.UserId = :userId " +
            "LEFT JOIN ScalaConf s ON s.UserId = :userId " +
            "LEFT JOIN GroovyConf g ON g.UserId = :userId " +
            "LEFT JOIN JavaConf j ON j.UserId = :userId " +
            "WHERE u.Id = :userId")
    List<Object[]> findAllByUserId(@Param("userId") long userId);

}
```

Hibernate takes care of mapping rows to entities. Each `Object[]` has all 5 entities (or nulls) as its elements. Selecting from `User` is to force the query to return results. Otherwise if first table returns nothing - the whole query returns nothing. Another downside is that if one table has 10 results and another has 1, the table with less results gets them duplicated.

As for performance (the sole point of doing all this), getting and processing results is 4-5 times faster than with 5 separate `SELECT`s.

Comment: Which version of hibernate you were using ?